# Paypal - CURL response is 0 in a new server (connection time out), it's ok in the old server

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to connect to Paypal Sandbox from a new server. If I test the code in my local computer (using XAMPP) it works fine. Also, if I test the code in my old server, it works ok too (same PHP version and libraries, and the new server should have the same configuration as the old (although I'm starting to doubt it...).

I redirect the CURL output to a file and this is what I get (similar output in curl_error()):

```
About to connect() to svcs.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
Trying 173.0.82.89... * Connection timed out
couldn't connect to host
Closing connection #0
```

This is the output of curl_getinfo():

```
[url] => https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?actionType=PAY...
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0.058702
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
```

This is the PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
    , array(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: '.$api_userid
    , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: '.$api_pass
    , 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: '.$api_signature
    , 'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: '.$api_appid
    , 'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
    , 'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV'
    )    
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I think the problem points to a server configuration issue, but I'm a little lost in wich way I have to look: PHP configuration, Apache, firewall, ... ¿any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to ping `svcs.sandbox.paypal.com`?

Comment: can you open `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/` in your browser? I can't.

Comment: seems as network problem and server fault maybe is more apropriate place to get help

Comment: The URL can't be loaded in a browser and doesn't respond to ping, but it is accesible with CURL from other servers, so it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It was a SSL configuration problem. The outgoing SSL port (443) was closed so the server couldn't establish a connection with Paypal.

Thanks for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

you could compare the phpinfo() list